# Как сделать чтобы при перемещения блока по оси Y, после него не оставалось пустого места и все остальные блоки занимали его место

Tags: html, css

У меня есть три блока(Block_1 Block_2 Block_3). Все они стоят друг под другом, для Block_1 применено свойство position: relative; top:-53px; То есть я переместил его вверх на 53px  и осталось пустое место, на котором он стоял до этого, как сделать чтобы остальные блоки( Block_2 и Block_3) стягивались на его место и заполнили пробел?

Comment: Разметку и стили покажите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как сделать чтобы остальные блоки( Block_2 и Block_3) стягивались на его место и заполнили пробел?

Для смещения можно использовать другие свойства `css`.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#Block_2 {
  margin-top: -53px;
  /* Для демонстрации */
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='Block_1'></div>
<div id='Block_2'></div>
<div id='Block_3'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)